# Name an output column created with case in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, switch-statement

Is it possible to name the output column created with `case` ("switch") in a PostgreSQL `SELECT` statement? It appears from the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-conditional.html) that this is not possible. An example usage of what I would like to do is:

`SELECT CASE (column) WHEN 1 THEN 'One' END AS 'TheColumn' FROM TABLE ;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works for me (pg-9.1)

```
CREATE TABLE one
    ( one INTEGER
    );
INSERT INTO one(one) values ( 0), (1), (NULL);

SELECT case one 
        when 1 then 'one'
        when 0 then 'zero'
        else 'other' 
       end AS the_one
FROM one;
```

So, the single quotes (that you used to quote the aliased column name) should have been double quotes (or absent).

The result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
UPDATE 3
 the_one 
---------
 one
 zero
 other
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example using either no quotes or double quotes works in PostgreSQL 8.4.12 as well.

Comment: It was only the quoting. I tend to avoid MixedCaseIdentifiers, thus avoiding quoting. The rules: single quotes := string literals; double quotes := identifiers.